# How can I control the location of the table of contents in R Markdown (PDF output)?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

The YAML header:

```
---
subtitle: "subtitle"
title: "title"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: true
---
```

This places the table of contents at the very beginning of the document but I would like to have it after the two first pages.

Does anyone know how to manage this? I would prefer not to use too much LaTeX.

Comment: I think you will need to use a [custom LaTeX template](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-template.html). I guess you want to move lines 477–503 of [default.latex](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/templates/default.latex) behind the two pages you want to add. But: What should be the content if these two pages? Some static content (probably simple) or the first two pages of your RMarkdown output (i.e., Pandoc's `$body$`)? I have no idea how you could split the latter ...

Comment: The first two pages are a front with the title and the second are edition details. What I am coming with as solution is just to have different Rmd documents for section and later joining them together (the PDFs outputs)- not ideal, but it is something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first two pages shoud contain static content (not generated in the body of the R Markdown document), then moving the table of contents to page 3 can be achieved with small modifications in the LaTeX template used by Pandoc.

As explained in [The Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-template.html), the default LaTeX template is [this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/1f1a30bbf6aa6d1c1dc60ac9d97560346066d02f/data/templates/default.latex) ([latest version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/pandoc/master/data/templates/default.latex)).

1. Download that file and save it in the directory of your RMD file. In my example below I named the file `toc-at-page3-template.tex`.
2. Edit the template: For example, after line 476 (i.e., before `$if(toc)$`), add

   ```
    \begin{center}
    Custom Stuff
    \end{center}

    \clearpage

    \begin{center}
    More Custom Stuff
    \end{center}

    \clearpage
   ```
3. In your RMD file, enable the custom template:

   ---

   ```
    output:
      pdf_document:
        toc: true
        template: toc-at-page3-template.tex
    ---

    Foo.
   ```

**Output:**
(click on thumbnails to enlarge)

[image: Output page 1]
[image: Output page 2]
[image: Output page 3]